# Which subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ are normal? When is $\operatorname{GL}_n(F) \cong\operatorname{SL}_n(F) \times F^* I_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider these subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$, where $F$ is a field and $n\in\Bbb N$

- $\operatorname{SL}_n(F)$
- $\operatorname{diag}_n(F)$
- $F^* I_n$ ($F^*$ times $I_n$, i.e. all $f\in F^*$ times $I_n$)

---

Questions:

1. Show that $\operatorname{SL}_n(F)$ is normal in $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$
2. Show that $F^* I_n$ is normal in $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$
3. When specifically is $\operatorname{diag}_n(F)$ normal in $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$? (note: not true in general)
4. When specifically is $\operatorname{GL}_n(F) \cong\operatorname{SL}_n(F) \times F^* I_n  $? (also not true generally)

---

Comments:
(1) easy. (4) My initial thoughts is true when n is odd, since when n is even in $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R \bigcap I_n$ is multivalued.

Comment: 1. Take $S \epsilon Sl_n(F)$. Then for all $g \epsilon Gl_n(F)$ 
the $det(gS{g^-}^1) = det(g)det(S){det(g)^-}^1 = det(S) = 1$ therefore $gS{g^-}^1 \epsilon $ $Sl_n(F)$ $\Rightarrow$ $Sl_n(F)$ is normal.

Comment: (4) Construct a projection $\operatorname{GL}_n F \to \operatorname{SL}_n F$, use this: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/splittinggp.pdf

Comment: (1) Is $\operatorname{SL}_n$ a kernel of some group homomorphism?

Comment: (1, continued) As a side quest, prove that despite its ridiculously looking definition, this homomorphism is a natural transformation.

Comment: I have observed the map 
$$Sl_n(F) \mapsto Gl_n(F) \mapsto F^*$$ 
Where $Gl_n(F) \mapsto F^*$ through determinant map.

Comment: Also I know $F^* \mapsto Gl_n(F)$ by multiplying by $I_n$.

Comment: (3) is true if and only $n=1$ or $|F|=2$. (I am assuming that ${\rm Diag}_n(F)$ does not include the zero matrix.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (4), note that $GL_n(F)$ has all possible determinants whereas the right side has only $n$th powers as determinants.  So a necessary condition for (4) is that every element of $F$ must have an $n$th root in $F$.  Furthermore, in order for (4) to hold, $SL_n(F) \cap F^*I_n$ must consist only of the identity.  So every element of $F$ must have a *unique* $n$th root in $F$.  You can check that this necessary condition is also sufficient for (4).

Some examples of $(F,n)$ where this is satisfied: When $F=\mathbb{R}$ and $n$ is odd (which you sort of alluded to in your original post); when $F$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$, and $n$ is a power of $p$.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered finite fields like that, very helpful.

Comment: I don't get it :( $\operatorname{GL}_n F$ retracts on $\operatorname{SL}_n F$ by dividing by the determinant, what prevents it from being a homomorphism in the cases that you presented? I mean, the short exact sequence has to not left-split, or else it's a direct product, right?

Comment: @Alexei It can't be a direct product if the intersection of $SL_n(F)$ and $F^*$ is nontrivial, for example.

Comment: I am missing something.  I agree that $\det:GL_n(F)\rightarrow F^\ast$ is surjective, and the map $\det':SL_n(F)\times F^\ast I_n\rightarrow F^\ast$ given by $\det'(A,B) = \det(B)$ only has $n$th powers in its image, but why would an isomorphism $\phi:GL_n(F)\rightarrow SL_n(F)\times F^\ast I_n$ necessarily have to satisfy $\det'\circ \phi = \det$?  Or am I misinterpreting what is meant by $\cong$?

Comment: I assumed that the OP didn't mean an arbitrary isomorphism here, but only whether the obvious map given by the inclusion maps of $SL_n(F)$ and $F^*I_n$ into $GL_n(F)$ is an isomorphism.